# Config the connection string of Entity Framwork to allow proxy

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Now I have the connection string to SQL Server using `EF6` like this:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.DatabasesMappers.MyDBMapper.csdl|res://*/Data.DatabasesMappers.MyDBMapper.ssdl|res://*/Data.DatabasesMappers.MyDBMapper.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
data source=tcp:mydb.mydns.com,23455;
initial catalog=MyDB;
user id=MyUser;
password=ThePassword;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

It's not work on the network that need proxy to be able to connect to the internet. What I could add to the connection string to connect through a proxy?

Thanks

Comment: you can't connect through a proxy if the port isn't open in the proxy server; that's kinda the whole point behind a proxy to begin with.

Comment: So, from this I understand that the StringConnection not need to be edited. I must verify the firewall roles to grant access to the IPServer and outbound Port_Range ?